# $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. does not hold for integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal M_{\lambda^*})$ and $f, f_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

I know that the following statement is not true in general:

> If $f_n, f$ are integrable and $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise a.e., then: $\int f_n d \lambda \rightarrow \int f d \lambda$.

But is there any example which really shows that the statement is not true?

Comment: [This sequence](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txte/3/gifa3/pc3ea3al.gif) converges to the function zero but their integrals are all $1$.

Comment: Does your book have Fatou's lemma?  It is an inequality.  Perhaps there is an example there to illustrate that strict inequality can occur.  And perhaps that example also has $f_n$ converging pointwise.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I must be missing something, maybe what you  mean by "this might be true": If that means what it seems to mean then it seems to me that you posted a counterexample using a non-atomic measure and then five minutes _later_  commented it might be true for non-atomic measures...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I got it backwards haha. I always mix up atomic and nonatomic measures for some reason.

Comment: Oh. Btw no, it's not true for atomic measures, for example $\frac1n\chi_{[0,n]}$ gives a counterexample in $\ell_1(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah good point! Very similar to my other example.

Comment: And is there also a good example for this: If $f_n,f$ are integrable and $ \int f_n d \lambda \rightarrow \int f d \lambda$, then it does NOT follow in general that $ \int | f_n−f| d \lambda \rightarrow 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f_n(x) = n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}(x)$ with the usual Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Another good example is $f_n(x) = \chi_{[n, n+1]}(x)$ which shows that it isn't just the non-atomic nature of the reals that gives it: the unboundedness does, too. I wonder if some mild constraints can be placed on the measure space to guarantee the result holds (without dropping to finite/counting measure spaces..).

Comment: And is there also a good example for this: If $f_n, f$ are integrable and $\int f_n d \lambda \rightarrow \int f d \lambda$, then it does NOT follow in general that $\int |f_n - f| d \lambda \rightarrow 0$.